# Problema en un registro de usuario

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

recurro nuevamente a uds ya que se me quemaron los papeles... ya no se cuál puede ser el problema. Estoy con un sistema de registro, al que le agregue la validación por recaptcha de google. 
La validación funciona perfecto, la cuestión es que al verificar que el usuario es "HUMANO" cargo a continuación toda la secuencia de validaciones que se agregan en el formulario. 
Estuve detectando que el error se me produce en el proceso de grabar los datos en la tabla usuarios. Para guardar los datos llamo a una función en PHP que es la siguiente:

```
function registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario, $usuclase){
$ul_list = json_encode($usuclase);

global $mysqli;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, nombre, correo, activacion, token, id_tipo, clase, nrologins) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssisisi', $usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario, $ul_list, $nrologins);

if ($stmt->execute()){
    return $mysqli->insert_id;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

}

El error que me tira es que esta función retorna "0"... estuve viendo todos los datos que se pasan a la función y son todos correctos.
Quiero destacar que la variable ul_list es un array que paso luego de que el usuario en el proceso de registro selecciona en un select multiple varias opciones, levantando los codigos de las selecciones realizadas... 
Ese array lo guardo en el campo CLASE...
Como les conté, estuve viendo cada uno de los campos que mando a la función y estan todos bien... me temo que el error esté en cómo guardo ese dato (el array) en la base de datos... 
Me dan una mano ? se los agradezco mucho...

Comment: esto es un insert. que esperas que devuelva?

Comment: como veras me devuelve el valor del id insertado... si no realiza el insert devuelve cero...

Comment: ah ok.. no me habia quedado claro, mi error.. el insert, en la base de datos, con esos parametros, anda?

Comment: siempre me devuelve "cero" osea... no realiza el insert

Comment: aun no probe hacer el insert a mano en la bd... pero pruebo en dos minutos y les comento...

Comment: En ningún momento asignas un valor a variable `$nrologins`

Comment: estás seguro que tu tabla tiene un `autoincrement` ?

Comment: TIENES RAZON !!! no le estoy pasando ese parámetro !!!...

Comment: como comenta @jecorrales `deberias de compartir la Solucion para otros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como sugiere @jasilva comparto la solución a este problema que tuve. Tengo una función hecha en PHP a la cual luego de las validaciones, del nombre de usuario, password, hash del password, etc. a la cual le mando todos los valores para registrar al usuario en la base de datos.
La función, se las presento:

```
function registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario, $usuclase, $nrologins){
 $ul_list = json_encode($usuclase);
 global $mysqli;
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, nombre, correo, activacion, token, id_tipo, clase, nrologins) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
 $stmt->bind_param('ssssisisi', $usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario, $ul_list, $nrologins);

 if ($stmt->execute()){
    return $mysqli->insert_id;
 } else {
    return 0;
 }
 }
```

Básicamente es una función que como verán devuelve el numero de id insertado, caso contrario devuelve cero. Después en el código analizo el valor que retorna esta función, si es cero, definitivamente hay un problema en esta función... caso contrario si el valor es distinto de cero, todo continúa hacia adelante.
El problema que tenía y como bien me señalaron, era un parámetro de la definición de la función que no lo estaba pasando y que estaba definido en el insert.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias al aporte de Matías Olivera, me hizo destacar que no estaba pasando uno de los parámetros que estaba utilizando en el query de insert... 
Desde ya, muy agradecido. Se vuelve a corroborar aquello de que cuatro ojos ven mejor que dos...